# Is the colon of Python assigning a value？What does Python do in this step?

Tags: python, syntax

I saw a novel Python syntax，like this

```
test:[123,"abc"]
test:"123"
```

But is not a Assignment of variables.

`print(test)`

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 print(test)

NameError: name 'test' is not defined

**What does Python do in this step?**

Comment: I suggest that you haven’t seen this at all.

Comment: @quamrana I suggest that you try it first. It is actually valid python.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak: It's valid, but it's unlikely they saw anything like `test:[123,"abc"]` unless it was already in the context of someone asking "what is this weird syntax doing".

Answer (score 0):

what you saw probably was a dictionary like this :

```
exmaple_dict = {
   "test": [123, "abc"],
   "test2": "123"
}
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp for more information.

Comment: I don't think it's a dictionary，The rule before the colon must be a variable naming rule, not a string or something。

Comment: It is a type annotation. Not a dictionary-entry.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to another answer this is actually valid python code!

This is called a `type-hint` as specified in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Basically it tells the programmer and IDE what type a variable should be but has no effect at runtime.

When you only type `test:"abc"` (equal to `test:str`) it does not actually define `test`, so you get a `NameError` when you try to acces `test` later